# Parse cloud function return always method name in response

Tags: parse-platform

I am new to parse and facing issue don't know why this happens.
I have deployed default hello function on parse and i am calling it using parse api but response always return function name.

below is my deployed method

```
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function (request, response) {    
response.error("Hello World");    
});
```

this is url that i am calling https://api.parse.com/1/hooks/functions/hello

and this is response

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "functionName": "hello"
    }
]
}
```

it return function name instead of hello world. what is i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong URL. This is a cloud function, not a web hook. The URL should be:

```
https://api.parse.com/1/functions/hello
```

Comment: thanks and also i have done HTTP verb from GET to POST and then after it worked.